# Intercepting http data sent from mobile app while mobile phone is using a proxy

Tags: http, proxy, charles-proxy

I want to read http requests coming from an app on my iphone, but I want to see the difference the location makes. I know that to use http readers like Charles you need to setup their proxy. So is it possible to layer proxies? Like have the Charles proxy send the request to another proxy in a different country.

I tried searching the web and also tried some tools in Charles, but didn’t found anything

Comment: Of course it is possible to configure Charles to use an upstream proxy (or "external proxy" as Charles calls it) https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/external-proxies/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn’t find it before